# Excel spends a very long time calculating several COUNTA UNIQUE equations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My excel spends a very long time calculating after pasting a COUNTA UNIQUE equation in 200 cells, it nearly doesn't work..this is the equation:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(IF(OR('full data'!$C:$C=$A3,'full data'!$Q:$Q="Sold"),
IF('full data'!$K:$K>=F3,IF('full data'!$K:$K<=H3,TEXT('full data'!$K:$K,"m")))),
TEXT('full data'!$K:$K,"m")<>"")))-1
```

the above equation is copied & pasted in 200 rows, & the file nearly stops after pasting.

is this normal? & what other equations i can use in replace of this combined above one?

i tried the above mentioned equation

Comment: No wonder, you're using full columns here.

Comment: Try to change, `COUNTA()` to `ROWS()` and `IF()` to `IFS()`, and avoid using the full columns as mentioned above ^^^.